# Unclear why aptitude marks package as broken

Tags: debian, aptitude

I have a situation where aptitude marks a package `cgroup-bin` as broken:

```
$ aptitude search '^cgroup-bin$'
pB  cgroup-bin ...
```

In its UI, aptitude provides the following explanation:

```
Some dependencies of cgroup-bin are not satisfied:
* cgroup-bin depends on cgroup-tools
```

Both `dpkg -l cgroup-bin` and `dpkg -l cgroup-tools`  issue `dpkg-query: no packages found matching ...` because neither package is installed.

Both `apt-cache policy cgroup-bin` and `apt-cache policy cgroup-tools` identify version 0.41-6 from the Debian repository as candidate versions.

`aptitude show cgroup-bin` lists these (relevant) dependencies:

```
Depends: cgroup-tools
```

`aptitude show cgroup-tools` lists those:

```
Breaks: cgroup-bin (< 0.40~rc1-3~)
Replaces: cgroup-bin (< 0.40~rc1-3~)
```

I have another machine which has the same properties but where the package is not marked as broken.

What is going on here? Why is package `cgroup-bin` marked as broken (when from the dependencies it would seem that versions 0.41-6 can live in unison) and how can I remedy the situation?